# Get attributes of class item from string associated with class item

Tags: python

I have a niche problem. I create a class classA, with attributes name and number. Once a class item is created, its name is stored as a string in a list, namesList. Later in the code, namesList prints and the user can enter a string input. If that input matches a string in namesList, I want the program to print the number attribute associated with that class item. How should I do this?

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect the line of code `classA(example, 5)` to *do*? In your own words, what *is* a class, and what do you think it is *for*?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
namesList = []

class classA:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        namesList.append(self.name)

example_Class = classA('example', 5)
userChoice = input('Which name do you need the number for?')

for name in namesList:
    if name == userChoice:
        print('The number is', example_Class.number)
```

You have to set `classA('example', 5)` equal to a variable `example_Class` and then if you want to access the number value stored it's just `example_Class.number`

**EDIT**

This code ought to work regardless of how many class items there are:

```
class Iterator(type):
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls.namesList)


class ClassA(metaclass=Iterator):
    namesList = []

    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.namesList.append(self)


example_Class1 = ClassA('one', 8)
example_Class2 = ClassA('two', 7)
example_Class3 = ClassA('three', 6)

userChoice = input('Which name do you need the number for?')

for class_name in ClassA:
    if class_name.name == userChoice:
        print('The number is', class_name.number)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution. I think I was not clear enough in the question or the example code. For this code, that solution would work, but in my program, the user can add any number of class items, so I cannot hard-code in example_Class.number here, and instead need a generic way to do this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for clearing that up. I was actually able to find a similar situation on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126100/recording-all-instances-of-a-class-python). I've updated my answer to a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassA` is just a class. You tried to reference it in the last line which leads to an error. Instead of doing that appending the object to the list would be better because then you can individually get the value back from the object while searching in the array.

```py
namesList = []

class classA:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        namesList.append(self)

    def getNumber(self):
        return self.number

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

example = 'c'
classA(example, 5)
userChoice = input('Which name do you need the number for?')
for name in namesList:
    if name.getName() == userChoice:
        nameIndex = namesList.index(name)
        print(nameIndex)
        print('The current price for', name.getNumber())
```